# DataTables dynamic edit/delete links based on user permissions

Tags: javascript, jquery, datatables

I have a Datatable (Boostrap4), where I need edit and delete links for each row.   What I'm having trouble figuring out is how to dynamically create those links based on user.  I need the edit and delete links to only appear for the currently logged in users own items (and no one elses), if possible.

I know I can wrap the 'defaultContent' line with PHP tags and perform logic. What I'm missing is if there's any way to compare (say) the First and Last name to see if that person matches the logged in user to control what items have the edit/delete links.

```
aoColumns: [
    { mData: 'first_name' } ,
    { mData: 'last_name' },
    { mData: 'note' },
    {
        data: null,
        className: "left",
        defaultContent: '<a style="display:inline-block;" href="edit.php" class="editor_edit">Edit</a> / <a href="delete.php" class="editor_remove">Delete</a>'
    }                   
]
```

Comment: Hello Reno, what have you done allready?

Comment: Hey Reno, you can add an extra row in data-tables with any condition, I can show you how if you can give us the while loop part of data-tables from your code.